# Enum case shadowing a built-in type name

Tags: swift, enums

I have created an enum

```
enum CellType {
    case String
    case TextView
    case Date
    case Int
    case Float
    case Radiobox(data: [String])
    case Checkbox
    case Email
    case Boolean
    case Image
    case Empty
}
```

Because I have a `case String` I can't use `String` in `case Radiobox(data: [String])`, instead I get an error. But if I remove the `case String`, there's no error.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All build-in types are under module `Swift` so you can refer to the build-in `String` type as `Swift.String`

```
enum CellType {
    case String
    case TextView
    case Date
    case Int
    case Float
    case Radiobox(data: [Swift.String])
    case Checkbox
    case Email
    case Boolean
    case Image
    case Empty
}

let a = CellType.String
let b = CellType.Radiobox(data: ["s"])
```